# How can i export multiple table values as a single file specific store

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

I need to export different tables values as same file,

Name - sku - category url - image path

**Name:**

category_products_entity_varchar :: [ value as name]  {attribute_id = 71}

**Sku:**

catalog_products_entity :: [sku]

**category url:**

category_products_entity_varchar  [value as category] {attribute_id = 57}

**image path :**

category_products_entity_media_gallery [value as image path]

Answer (score 0):

**QUERY :**

> SELECT cpev.value as Name,cpe.sku,gp.value category_url, ea.value image_path FROM catalog_product_entity cpe inner join (SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id="71") cpev on cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id inner join (SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery) ea on ea.entity_id=cpe.entity_id inner join ( SELECT category_id, product_id FROM catalog_category_product) eavv on cpe.entity_id =eavv.product_id inner join ( SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id='57') gp on eavv.category_id=gp.entity_id LIMIT 0 , 30

**SCRIPT :**

```
<?php

ini_set("memory_limit","-1");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180000); 

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);

$fopen = fopen('products.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("Name","sku","Category","image", "GalleryImages");// Add the fields you need to export
fputcsv( $fopen , $csvHeader,",");

foreach ($products as $product){ 

   $_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getId());
   $gallery_images=$_product->getMediaGalleryImages();

   $image =Mage::getBaseUrl('media')."catalog/product".$_product->getImage();

   foreach($gallery_images as $g_image) {
       $g_images.=$g_image['url']."\n";
   }
   $sku = $_product->getSku();
   $name= $_product->getName();
   $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
   fputcsv($fopen, array($name,$sku,implode(",",$categories),$image,$g_images), ",");
}
echo"Done";
fclose($fopen );
```

Comment: Thanks for your options, does u know sql script for that

Comment: SQL Script added @JeevaRathinam

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VJOU26m.png

Comment: same sku repeated more than one time. i think its default store types. how can i display only english language store

Comment: @JeevaRathinam same sku repeats due to multiple gallery images. One product can have more then one image.  If you want for specific store then update your question.

Comment: i am edited my question, how can i do that

Comment: @ Gopal Patel : Am edited my question

Comment: when i try your sql code its working in localhost, but not working in my cpanel

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/zUUolWQ.png

Comment: @JeevaRathinam use LIMIT 0 to 30 if it works then you have to change net_read_timeout option